# Pyspark: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 86.0 failed 1 times Possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks, parquet

I am facing some issues while writing parquet files from one blob to another. below is the code I'm using.

```
df = spark.read.load(FilePath1,
                     format="parquet", modifiedAfter=datetime)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false")
df.coalesce(1).write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save(FilePath2)
Error - 
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3 in stage 86.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 3.0 in stage 86.0 (TID 282) (10.0.55.68 executor driver): com.databricks.sql.io.FileReadException: Error while reading file dbfs:file.parquet. Possible cause: Parquet column cannot be converted.
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableInt cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.MutableLong.
```

any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [spark error reading parquet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51300978/spark-error-reading-parquet)

Answer (score 0):

- The cause of this error is possibly because of the decimal type of column is decoded into binary format by the vectorized Parquet reader.
- For reading datasets in Parquet files, the vectorized Parquet reader is enabled by default in Databricks Runtime 7.3 and higher. Binary, boolean, date, text, and timestamp are all atomic data types used in the read schema.
- The solution for this is, if your source data contains decimal type columns, you should disable the vectorized Parquet reader.
- To disable the vectorized Parquet reader at the cluster level, set `spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader`  to  `false`  in the cluster’s  [Spark configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/clusters/configure#spark-configuration)
- At the notebook level, you can also disable the vectorized Parquet reader by running:

  **spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.enableVectorizedReader","false")**

References:
[Apache Spark job fails with  Parquet column cannot be converted  error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/scala/spark-job-fail-parquet-column-convert)
[Pyspark job aborted error due to stage failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65671307/pyspark-job-aborted-error-due-to-stage-failure)